# C# - Compare two .csv files without a key or unique Id

Tags: c#

I have a two .csv files that are in the format

File1

```
ID,Name,Token
123,ABC,345
555,XYZ,777
777,YYY,765
666,UUU, 
543,MNO,
```

File2

```
ID,Name,Token
777,ABC,345
125,XYZ,999
976,RRR,
```

I have to compare these and exclude those employees who have same ID or/and same token because these employees are considered same.

So, in my above example, in File2
The employee Id 777 has two matching employees in File 1, the one that have 777 as token number and the one that have 777 as Id.

I have done file comparison before also and every time I have used hashtables/dictionaries where the ID/Token were unique for every employee so it was simple as I only had to compare keys. But here as we can see, one employee in File2 matches with 2 Employees in File1.

I assume to tackle this issue we can use a linear search and do a full scan of File1 for every employee of File2. But I think it would be useless as it would increase processing time a lot because in my file there would be hundreds of rows. For example, if File 2 has 400 rows and File 1 has 300, then for each employee in File2, the application would scan 300 times. This doesn't make sense.

What should I do in this case? Should I fix the data at source and eliminate these duplicates entries there only?

Please let me know if the problem statement doesn't make sense. I will try to explain more clearly. Thanks!

UPDATE- What I tried

I read File1 in a dictionary and then read File2 line by line and compared the ID and token. This works well for those employees that have unique id and token but for duplicates in the data it fails.

```
if((File2_ID).contains(File1_ID)|| (File2_Token).contains(File1_Token))
{
//do something
}
```

The issue with this approach is that the application checks employee ID 777 in File2 with the Id 777 in File 1, it thinks it has found it match , it processes the data and moves to the next line in File2. It doesn't consider employee with token number 777 in File1.

UPDATE 2 - I had forgotten to mention that tokens can be blank too.

I was wondering if I try some data cleansing thing. Create a functionality that removes these duplicates, and then add clean file in the application for comparison.

Comment: Create a class to represent a row. Read all rows and store it in a dictionary lookup key to list of rows. Done?

Comment: @ChristophLütjen I tried that but when I do ```if (Id in File2).contains(Id in File1) || (token in File2).contains(token in File1)``` , then it only considers the row that matches the ID and leaves the one with matching token. Here I have to link one ID in File2 with 2 employees of File1.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What .net version are you targeting? How big are your CSV files? If not very big then load them in to memory before doing the comparison.

Comment: Give a more complete example of input files and expected outputs.

Comment: @PiersMyers I have updated the question with the approach that I tried. My both  files will have around 500 rows. .Net version is 4.5 above.

Comment: Create a dictionary for every key to compare. From File1 create a dict based on Id and one based on token. When iterating File2 check id against both dicts and afterwards token against both dicts. Should still be fairly fast and I can't think of anything faster, because according to your description both key columns are independent.

Comment: @Oliver You approach seems good but I forgot to mention that in my files token can be blank too. Let me update the question. These blanks would create an issue in creating the token dictionary

Comment: That's just something to take care when creating the dicts. If the key value is null or empty, just skip it and don't add it to the dict.

Comment: @Oliver Okay will try your approach...thanks!

Comment: If you could describe in a bit more detail how are you going to handle duplicates, it would be easier to suggest a good approach. Something like "I need to delete from the second file the records which are present in the first file" or "If I find two matching records in file2 for some line from file1 then I need to leave only the one with matching ID and remove the one with matched token"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like the following to lookup by both ID and Token:

```cs
FileEntry foundById;
idMap.TryGetValue(File1_ID, out var foundById);

FileEntry foundByToken;
idToken.TryGetValue(File1_Token, out var foundByToken);

if (foundById && foundByToken)
{}
else if (foundById)
{}
else if (foundByToken)
{}
```